# The methods under @BeforeClass, @AfterClass, @BeforeMethod, @AfterMethod annotations are not working, only Suite annotations are working

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-eclipse

```
package com.edureka.testng1;

import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
public class AnnoitationsDemo {
    
    @BeforeSuite
    public void beforeSuiteMethod()
    {
        Reporter.log("Before suite Method",true);
    }
    
    @AfterSuite
    public void afterSuiteMethod()
    {
        Reporter.log("After suite method",true);
    }
    
    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClassMethod()
    {
        Reporter.log("Before suite method",true);
    }
    
    @AfterClass
    public void afterClassMethod()
    {
        Reporter.log("After class method", true);
    }
    
    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod()
    {
        Reporter.log("Before method",true);
    }
    
    @AfterMethod
    public void afterMethod()
    {
        Reporter.log("After method",true);
    }
}
```

```
package com.edureka.testng1;

import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TaskModuleScripts {
    
    @Test (groups = {"Smoke", "Task"})
    public void task1()
    {
        Reporter.log("task 1 method");
    }
    
    @Test (groups = {"Smoke", "Task"})
    public void atask2()
    {
        Reporter.log("task 2 method");
    }
    
    @Test
    public void task3()
    {
        Reporter.log("task 3 method");
    }
    
    @Test
    public void task4()
    {
        Reporter.log("task 4 method");
    }
}
```

I am expecting the methods under `@BeforeMethods` should run before every test method. I have included the `AnnoitationsDemo` class under `<Classes>` tag of `testng.xml`

Comment: Your `AnnoitationsDemo` (sic) class doesn't actually contain any tests. Add some and they'll run.